# Как вывести массив в столбик и без скобок в text widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

Вот код приложения, мне нужно вывести значения координат графика в соответствующие поля. Получение координат описывается в функции `getCoord()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy , QTableWidgetItem
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import design

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.graph)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.getGraphBtn.clicked.connect(self.drawGraph)
        self.getCoordBtn.clicked.connect(self.getCoord)
        x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
        y = np.sin(x)
    def getCoord(self):
        x = np.arange(0,50, 1)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.xField.setText(str(x.reshape(50, 1)))
        self.yField.setText(str(y.reshape(50, 1)))

    def drawGraph(self):
            x = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
            y = np.sin(x)
            self.figure.clear()
            plt.title('Рассчет АЧХ')
            plt.ylabel('k(w)')
            plt.xlabel('w')
            plt.plot(x,y)
            self.canvas.draw()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С вопросом разобрался, достаточно использовать `.append()`. 
Вот пример :

```
 def getCoord(self):
    x = np.arange(0,50, 1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    for i in x:
        self.field1.append("\n" + str(i))
    for i in y:
        self.field2.append("\n" + str(i)[:4])
```